# Are the Administrative Shares recreated upon login?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7

I have a user with local admin rights on his computer, that keeps deleting the Administrative Shares on his station, i.e. `\\machinename\c$`  and `d$`

Ignoring HR and Legal actions that can be taken, my question: are these folders recreated upon login?

If not, how can I make sure that they are, and is there a way I can prevent it as long as he has local admin rights (which the answer I believe will be NO )

Comment: If a user is deleting the admin shares you need to have a really good look at that machine. They must be doing it to hide something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The administrative shares are re-created at system boot, but it is possible to disable them permanently using a registry edit.

It's highly unlikely that there will be a way of preventing him from removing them without revoking him administrative rights. If you've asked him to stop removing the shares and he's ignoring you, isn't that reason enough to remove his admin rights until he stops being a &^%$?

EDIT: It's also possible to cause the shares to be re-created by restarting the `Server` service, without requiring a reboot. I suppose you could schedule a task on his machine to do this overnight or something like that.

Comment: You are right, but it's office polititcs I am trying to avoid (those damm C-level rights) - The registry to disable that is not thereh (lanserver->parameters...) so he didn't add them. And as I read, only the admin share is recreated NOT the root shares. is that true?

Comment: The term 'Administrative shares' covers all of them - the root of each fixed drive, and the admin$ share.

Comment: @Saariko - if someone has administrator rights, it is impossible to stop them doing whatever they like... that's the point of admin rights. You can, however, use GPOs to restrict what their account can see or do... this might be enough to discourage an idiot who likes to play with things rather than a malicious user. Ultimately though, this isn't a technical problem and while office politics aren't fun, they are a part of the job we all have to deal with.

Comment: Your EDIT is awsome :=-)